# How to add points in order along a stream reach in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis

I have a stream network in ArcGIS - i.e. a series of polylines, and along each stream part I have added points.  For each of the points I have extracted the height and flow from underlying rasters and I have also extracted data from the intersecting polylines including minimum, mean and max height of the polyline, the HydroID and the nextdownID.  The points also have their own ID but I have noticed these are not in order.

What I would like is to add stepID to each of the points, where at the beginning of each river reach (each polyline) the first point is step 1 and this increments upwards until the end of the reach.  So if there were 10 points along a polyline, the first point would have a stepID value of  1 and the last point would have a stepID value of 10.

This sounds quite easy but not sure how to do it.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct points along the line at specific intervals using the construct points tool/function.

Click the Edit tool Edit Tool on the Editor toolbar.
Click the line feature along which you want to generate points.
Click the Editor menu and click Construct Points.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000029000000.htm

To automate the numbering, you might look into flipping the lines so all the tails point in one direction - up or downstream.  Double click on a line, then right click to see the "flip" command.  If you use the points set up from the method above, it might order from tail to head.

Another option is to create your own field for the stepID.  Create a attribute join to the stream segment, and give each joined record a unique number.  Go through your records selecting each group of ten, then sort by FID (check these are in order) then calculate value for stepID = FID - x 
where x = the lowest FID in the stream segment's stepID.  This thought might help you figure out how to coax the numbers out correctly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  The Edit tool is not an option as I have hundreds of thousands of lines.  The polyline shapefile is actually a drainage line so the attribute knows where it is going to (i.e. downstream). I'll try creating my own field and see what happens.

Comment: You should try a batch construct points - not manually enter each point.  I think it should let you add x many points to every line spaced at a defined interval.  I'd do it in ArcCatalogue, open the construct points tool in ArcToolBox, right click and use batch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and solved it this way. It is NOT a pretty solution. Would love to hear if there is a more elegant way of doing this
.
For clarity I'll call the pointdataset you mention the 'inputpoints'.

**Step 1: getting the points in the right order**

- If your inputpoints are sometimes far away from the lines, first project them to your lines.
- Give your lines a unique line number and join it to the closest inputpoint features
- Generate points along lines: use your polylines and genarate a lot of points on them. I'll call this dataset the helperpoints. Fill in a distance that is smaller then the smallest distance between two of your inputpoints.
  Make sure your polylines have the right 'direction'. You can check it by using a symbology with arrows, and if needed correct it with the flip editing tool.
- Add an IDfield to your helperpoints, type float or double, and create sequential idnumbers in it (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137).
- Spatial join: the inputpoints are your target, the helperpoints the join features. Keep all the target features. You only need to join the IDfield from the helperpoints. Right click the IDfield in the field map, and make the merge rule 'Mean'. Set the Match option to 'within a distance', and make the search radius 1.5 x the distance that you used in the generate points along line step.
- Use the sort tool and sort your spatial join output on the IDfield you just added, then on the lineID you you added on step one. If you have the advanced licence you can do it at once.

**Step 2: Generating the StepID**

- Add a new field to your sort output, and call it StepID
- Use the field calculator to fill it. I used this code to make the numbering restart every time there is a new line.

```
rec=0 
oldid = -1 
def autoIncrement(lineid): 
    global rec 
    global oldid 
    pStart = 1  
    pInterval = 1 
    if rec == 0 or lineid!= oldid :  
        rec = pStart  
    else:
        rec += pInterval 
    oldid = lineid
    return int(rec)
```

Expression: `autoIncrement( !lineID! )`
Expression type: `Python`

It might still mess up if you have lines very close to each other, or have weird curls on the end. But for the rest this should work!